# How do I fade a BufferedImage when manipulating it's pixel data?

Tags: java, alpha

I am trying to do something I have never done before.
My goal is to be able to manipulate the opacity of a BufferedImage. First off, I do not use Graphics. I am developing a simple Game Engine and I only use pixel data from BufferedImages.

**What have I tried?**

I made my own "Image" class that takes in a BufferedImage.

```
BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(Image.class.getResourceAsStream(resourcePath));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    width = image.getWidth();
    height = image.getHeight();
    hasAlpha = image.getColorModel().hasAlpha();
    
    pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height,null,0,width);
```

After that I proceeded to my rendering code. I have a function called "drawImage()" that takes the image and it's data and then puts it out on a specific spot on the screen depending on the users wishes. I however want the user to choose it's opacity as well.

I started out by taking the pixel data for that pixel and I instead made a Color.

```
Color c = new Color(image.getPixels()[value2],true);
```

The "true" statement, what I know of, says that it should "care" about Alpha.

After that I place the pixel by using this code:

```
pixels[x + y * pWidth] = new Color(c.getRed(),c.getGreen(),c.getBlue(),alphaValue).getRGB();
```

This doesn't work. It doesnt output any errors and I can change the alphaValue to a number between 0 and infinity. However one issue I found is that it doesnt affect the image at all when I change the alpha from 255 to something like 50. It stays the same. The affect comes at 0-5. Another thing that I noticed is that when I set alphaValue to something like 2 I get an animation instead of the image with lower opacity. Sounds weird, that's why I provided a .GIF of the issue:

[image: Fade issue]

I guarantee you that there is no code that changes the alphaValue. During that "animation" it is set to 2 and nothing else.

So something is weird here and I wonder if you guys know the issue?

It might have something to do with the Image class and that I don't set it to *BufferedImage.RGBA* but I don't know how I can do so when I load an image?

If you need any more information, please leave a comment and I will provide more info!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
I clear the screen every 1/60 of a second by manipulating the backgrounds pixels (also a bufferedImage):

```
public void clear() {
    for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        pixels[i] = clearColor.getRGB();
    }
    
    
}
```

**Possible issue**

I did some troubleshooting and I found out that it actually somehow increased in opacity each frame as @Joni said. Somehow the opacity or alpha seems to increase each frame but I am clearing the screen between drawings. I will troubleshoot further.

**UPDATE**

I made so I could move the image around and found this weird behaviour:

[Link to Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2NMp.jpg)

It seems that the "alpha" isn't reset. I know that the RGB is being reset but something is really off when it comes to the Alpha.

I changed the clear function to this:

```
public void clear() {
    for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        pixels[i] = new Color(clearColor.getRed(),clearColor.getGreen(),clearColor.getBlue(),255).getRGB();
    }
    
    
}
```

And I defined clearColor as:

```
Color clearColor = new Color(Color.black.getRGB(),true);
```

That did however not work either. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Dammm i had an nice answer if it was android.

Down-scaling a image and drawing it ona  bigger size also has a effect of blur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your game engine is drawing the image on top of itself in a loop. After drawing it enough many times the effect is the same as not having used transparency at all. The lower the alpha, the longer it takes though: with 50% alpha you need 7 frames to get 99% opacity, with 5% alpha you need about 90 frames.

For example, suppose you are drawing a pixel value of 100 on a screen that's intially 0 (black) with 50% opacity. After the first frame, the output pixel value is .5*100 + .5*0 = 50. The second frame is drawn on top of the first frame, so the output pixel value is .5*100 + .5*50 = 75. The third frame, drawn on top of the second frame, will show .5*100 + .5*75 = 87.5.

To avoid this, you need to fill a solid background color under the image in every frame.

Comment: I changed my "clear color" to Color.white but it didn't make a difference. I don't quite understand what you are saying. How can the opacity go up to 99% when I set the alpha to 2 and I don't change it? How can me rendering the same image with the same alpha make it go to 99% opacity?

Comment: I am updating the frame every 1/60 of a second. So the old image is removed and a new one is rendered. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Where is the old image removed? Your code does not show that.

Comment: It doesn't due to me wanting to keep the problem simple. It is overdrawn by a clear function that sets all of the backgrounds (which also is a BufferedImage) pixels to a specific color.

Comment: I updated my question with an edit that shows the code.

Comment: Where do you draw all of this on the screen?

Comment: It's a game engine, it's not a small project so I understand that you might be confused. I draw in my "render" method but the "drawing" really happens in the code I mentioned above.

Comment: It wouldn't be much use but sure

Comment: OK. What does this draw on? I want to see the code that actually puts pixels in a screen buffer

Comment: Draw on? This is how it works. The screen is cleared by setting all pixels to black. Then I render the code above. I take the pixel data from an image and insert it on a specific spot on the  screen. After that it is cleared once again etc.

Comment: Can you prepare a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Without actual runnable code that produces the problem the only thing we can do is speculate and draw from past experiences when we have seen similar errors.

Comment: I dont think I will be able to do that as it will take a lot of code to just get this alpha error thing running